# Обработка закрытия android приложения

Tags: java, android, kotlin, app

товарищи разрабы! Пишу android приложение, в котором столкнулся с такой проблемой: я не знаю как програмно обработать выход из приложения. То есть, например: юзер закрыл приложение -> отработала функция. Есть у кого какие мысли?

Comment: https://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/60-urok-23-activity-lifecycle-v-kakih-sostojanijah-mozhet-byt-activity.html Это можно сделать в onDestroy(). Однако учтите, что вызов этой функции не гарантирован https://stackoverflow.com/a/18361887/7485582

Comment: А что вы понимаете под закрытием приложения в андроиде?

Answer (score 2):

В системе Андроид нет пользовательского понятия "закрыть приложение". Пользователь может "закрыть" все активити, но само приложение (объект Application) остается жить, пока система его не посчитает ненужным и не выгрузит.

Фактически, закрытие последней активити и воспринимается пользователем как закрытие самого приложения, хотя технически это и не так.

Поэтому считайте активити и когда остается 0 запущенных, делайте свое дело.